# Text gets blurry after CSS3 Transform (Translate) on Chrome Only

Tags: google-chrome, css

I've got a strange behavior over a common transform (translate) transition triggered by jQuery.css

Here is the working demo:

http://www2.madeinweb.com.br/jobs/adc/

I've been reading a bit about css3 transitions, and couldn't fix this tweak.

Anyone got any ideas over it?

Comment: I see nothing strange using chrome. What is the scenario to reproduce the bug on your site ?

Comment: The news feed was blurring the text. I've just managed to fix it removing the overflow. I don't know why exactly this was happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the article size. I'm not sure why, but fixing the overflow with box-sizing managed to fix it.